# Como fazer esta inserção de forma dinâmica?

Tags: php, mysql

> Como fazer esta inserção de forma dinâmica sabendo a quantidade total de colunas?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO VOT_PART_MUN_ZONA VALUES ( 

   '$dados[0]',
   '$dados[1]',
   '$dados[2]',
   '$dados[4]',
   '$dados[...]',
   '$dados[19]'

)");
```

Comment: Precisa dar mais detalhes, da vem as colunas. Em teoria o número de valores deve ser o mesmo de  colunas.

Comment: Isso não parece ser uma boa ideia. É bom especificar os campos onde você está inserido. Assim, fica fácil de outra pessoa que vai mexer no seu código futuramente entender o que está sendo feito ali.

Comment: Concordo com @WallaceMaxters melhor especificar o que está mandando e aonde do que depois se bater futuramente para saber o que está vindo/passando;

Comment: O que eu quero dizer assumindo que a quantidade de colunas seja exatamente a quantidade de dados inseridos, como inserir estes dados que estão num arquivo de texto sem repetir todos os itens desse array !!! Ninguém vai mexer no  código mas se eu tiver por exemplo **$dados[500]** imagina especificar 1 por 1 !!!!

Comment: Uma tabela com 500 colunas? Acho meio difícil. E, se existir, foi mal estruturada. Para saber isso, você tem que contar o número de colunas. A não ser que queira usar um `'"' . implode('","', $dados) . '"'` para fazer isso. Mas já adianto: Isso seria uma senhora gambiarra. `sprintf('INSERT INTO tabela VALUES("%s")', implode('","', $dados))`

Comment: Seria algo como isso? `INSERT INTO 'usuarios' ('id', 'nome', 'email') VALUES (NULL, 'Thiago', 'contato@thiagobelem.net'), (NULL, 'Fulano da Silva', 'fulano@email.com'), (NULL, 'Ciclano', 'ciclano@uol.com.br')` Fonte: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/cadastrando-multiplos-registros-no-mysql-ao-mesmo-tempo/

Comment: O cara teria que reordenar o array se o campo da tabela fosse mudado de posição :(

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de não ser uma prática recomendada, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

Suponhamos que seu array tenha `500` dados, como os gerados abaixo pela função `range`.

Poderíamos utilizar a função `implode` para poder trazer todos os valores.

```
$dados = range(1, 500);


$insert = sprintf('INSERT INTO tabela VALUES("%s")', implode('","', $dados));


echo $insert;
```

http://ideone.com/BV4Byu

A recomendação seria você informar os campos onde você vai inserir esses dados. Um dos benefícios que podem ser citados é a facilitação da leitura do código, seja quem foi que o for o editar.